print template using tauri and reactjs without print prompte of browser and print in silent
Has anyone implemented a feature similar to this: printing an HTML template using Tauri and ReactJS without triggering the print prompt in the browser and ensuring silent printing?
i dont want to use tauri-plugin-printer it makes a prompt on application window
I've tried the Tauri printer plugin, but it doesn't suit my needs. I'm seeking assistance from anyone who has successfully achieved printing an HTML template using Tauri and ReactJS without triggering the browser's print prompt and ensuring silent printing. Can anyone who has accomplished this help me achieve the same?
It doesn't matter if you accomplished this using another framework or vanilla JavaScript. If you've achieved this with any method, your insights would be greatly appreciated.

did you got workaround for this ?
